# Problems ubuntu live usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I will preface this by saying that I am not extremely knowledgeable (in fact, I am not very knowledgeable, so my terms may also be wrong).
I installed ubuntu (dual boot) via usb and, once a few problems were solved, it worked like a charm.
I then had the unhealthy idea of putting in a specific kernel for the Surface so that I could take advantage of the touch (I have a Surface Laptop 3), and from that moment on ubuntu wouldn't boot.

The next steps were: looking for guides to fix it, constantly failing, uninstalling linux, formatting the partition, deleting the grub (I thought and think that's where the problem is but it's just a feeling).

The only step (in my mind) to fix it was to reinstall via usb ubuntu in dual boot. I open rufus, redo the same steps, go into uefi, fix things as usual... it no longer starts linux in live usb.
The white letters come out but it can't reach a file (if I find the text I'll update the question) but nothing is clickable or editable.

I make a billion attempts with a billion guides or questions on the forums... nothing to do now not even the writing (at the discretion of formatting the boot key it changes whether it gives me the writing or not) but only the persistent white window of the surface... in all this Windows still works...

Now I tried (stupidly) to restore the pc but it didn't work....
I really need ubuntu in dual boot... asking for help, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a good backup of Windows. We see users click on full drive install & then totally erase Windows. You should always be able to boot live installer from UEFI boot menu as you did first time. Did at some point you write data to installer not your system? Did Windows updates turn fast start up/hibernation or bit locker back on?

Comment: Having a go (and breaking it) is how you learn. You might have lost Windows completely though. Perhaps have another go at resinstalling Ubuntu with the [linux-surface](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface) kernel mod? [Debian packages](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/releases/tag/debian-6.7.9-1) are available. Keep the old kernel as a GRUB option, means you can go back if there is a problem